# Contact Form 7 redirect with on_sent_ok doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I tried using the `on_sent_ok` to redirect after form submit for Contact Form 7 (Wordpress plugin), but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://www.company.com/thank-you/');"
```

Why wouldn't this work?

I am using CF7 versions 2.2.1 and Wordpress 3.5.0.

Comment: Note that now (2018) `on_sent_ok` [is deprecated](https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on_sent_ok not working in Contact Form 7 normally indicates a Javascript conflict with either your current WordPress theme or one of the other plugins you are using - see [Contact Form 7 Email Issues](http://contactform7.com/faq/#Contact_Form_7_Email_Issues) - there is a link there that covers **Javascript Conflicts**.

**Remember that a problem in one script can cause issues in another.**
For example, some jQuery errors can stop jQuery processing any more script, which can make the culprit hard to find.

A jQuery error in one of your plugins or your themes javascript files can stop jQuery processing before it gets to the CF7 script.

Use [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) or [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to examine Javascript conflicts in detail.

See http://wiki.simple-press.com/installation/troubleshooting/plugin-conflicts/ for general guidance.

Comment: Thanks. How do I identify a conflict with a plugin or a theme? How can I know if it's a conflict?

Comment: Works OK after updating Contact form from version 2.1 to 3.7 (and Wordpress update to 3.8.1).

Answer (score 4):

Contact Form 7 Thank You Page Redirects THE OLD METHOD: on_sent_ok hook is no longer recommended.  I have a code you can copy and paste. You can add that method bottom of your functions.php file, add this code:

```
<pre>
<code>
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   if ( '97' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
    location = 'http://www.vizistata.com/affordable-logo-designs.php';
    } 
    else if ( '634' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // 634 is the form id
        location = 'http://www.vizistata.com/#blog';
    } 

    else if ( '635' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // 635 is the form id
        location = 'http://www.vizistata.com/#contact';
    } 

    else if ( '636' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
        location = 'http://www.vizistata.com/#services';
    } 

    else if ( '94' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
        location = 'http://www.vizistata.com/#about';
    } 


    else { // Sends submissions on all unaccounted for forms to the third thank you page
        location = 'http://www.vizistata.com/';
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}</pre>
</code>
```

Comment: this should appears on top as it is the latest and recommended solution.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with my own Wordpress theme. After an hour I understood that forgot to add `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in footer.php, so important Contact 7 scripts doesn't load. When I add it everthing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

in additional settings

Comment: Same problem here: it seems that Contact Form 7 puts these invisible characters after the url: "%E2%80%8E" and then tells me the url doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried both solutions: on_sent_ok didn't work and adding redirect javascript didn't do the job either. 
Eventually, I found myself editing the file 'submissions.php' inside the 'modules' folder of 'contact-form-7'. 
look for: `private function submit()`
in there, look for `elseif ( $this->mail()` I've commented `$this->response = $contact_form->message( 'mail_sent_ok' );`  and just put `header("Location: www.somesite.com/");` 
Works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a client with 21 JS errors in the theme that won't let me update said theme, and this was the only solution that got the redirect to work :)

Comment: @KerynGill - It's been a while since I posted this. I'm glad it helped. Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Contact form 7 Redirecting to Another URL After Submissions

First you need to update contact form 7 on new version i try it on v7.4.9 and then place a contact form short code in any page and place this JS script any where on page and change url where need to redirect your page after submission

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
</script>
```

For more info click contact form 7 official site  https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem in contact form 7 latest version 4.8.1 .

finally solved issue using custom jquery code.

```
if ($('.wpcf7-form.sent').length) {
      $(location).attr('href', 'http://www.example.com')
    }
```

Note: Contact form 7  form successful  submit  adding class "sent" to form field .

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code for this. I put it in one line to just save a few characters. If necessary, you can still work with is_page or something so that the JavaScript is only output for pages that also contain a form.

```
/* Inline script for redirect cf7 to thank you page */
// https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/
add_action('wp_footer', 'cf7__redirect_thankyoupage');
function cf7__redirect_thankyoupage() {
    ?><script>document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent',function(event) {location='/thank-you';}, false );</script><?php
}
```

And if you are using WPML and only want to output it for one language, then you can use the following code:

```
if (null !== ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "en"){ ... }
```

It is best to set the thank you pages to Noindex (via Robots.txt / Meta).